# Why is my regex returning 2 results if there is only one in the string?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract an ID from a string with python3. The regex returns more then one item, despite only having one in the text:

> text_total = 'Lore Ippsum Ref. 116519LN Perlmutt'

```
>>> re.findall(r"Ref\.? ?(([A-Z\d\.]+)|([\d.]+))", text_total)

[('116519LN', '116519LN', '')]
```

I am looking for a single trimed result, if possible without beeing a list anyway.

That's why my original line is:

```
 [x for x in re.findall(r"Ref\.? ?(([A-Z\d\.]+)|([\d.]+))", text_total)][0]
```

The regex has an OR as I am also trying to match

> Lore Ippsum Ref. 1166AB.39AZU2.123 Lore Ippsum

How can I retrieve just one result from the text and match both conditions?

Comment: Please [check the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall). The tuple represents all the groups in your regular expression.

Comment: If you only want one result - then you don't want to use `findall` - consider using 
 `re.match` or `re.search` instead?

Comment: @JonClements I am not getting a result with re.match, while re.search returns: <re.Match object; span=(47, 60), match='Ref. 116519LN'>. I am just looking for the ID: 116519LN to be extracted.

Comment: @merlin and when you get that match object using re.search, what does that object's `.groups()` return ?

Comment: It returns: 'Ref. 116519LN'

Comment: You have two capturing groups that contain one thing. That's the reason. Please see the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your groups inside your OR group, so to speak, are "capturing groups". You need to make them non capturing using the `?:` syntax inside those groups, and allow the outer group to stay as a capturing group.

```
import re
text_total = 'Lore Ippsum Ref. 116519LN Perlmutt'
re.findall(r"Ref\.? ?((?:[A-Z\d\.]+)|(?:[\d.]+))", text_total)
#result ['116519LN']
```

Note that this still gets you multiple matches if there are many. You can use re.search for just first match.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need an or, you can do `Ref\.? ?([a-zA-Z. 0-9]+)` (note the space at the end of the regex, it will be used as the ending for the match.

```
import re
pattern = r"Ref\.? ?([a-zA-Z. 0-9]+) "
text_total = "Lore Ippsum Ref. 116519LN Perlmutt"
results = re.findall(pattern, text_total)
print(results[0])
```